# Como insertar una imagen dentro de un marcador utilizando wikitude sdk?

Tags: javascript, android, wikitude

Por favor quisiera una ayuda, recomendación o sugerencia.
Estoy desarrollando mi proyecto de realidad aumentada y geolocalizacion utilizando wikitude sdk y android studio. Lo que quiero es insertar una imagen que se encuentra ubicada en un web service, si fuera asi tendria que modificar en el marker.js? Adjunto una imagen de referencia de como es que seria el marcador con una imagen. De antemano gracias.[image: ![Marcador con imagen de punto de interes]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbjH5.jpg)